# Continuous deployment for node.js applications using CI and CodeDeploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy

I am having trouble figuring out how to setup continuous deployment for my node.js application (through aws CodeDeploy). So far I completed following steps:

1. Created IAM user with required permissions
2. Created Elastic Beanstalk instance running node.js
3. Created CodeDeploy application and linked it to my EC2 instance and IAM user

I have also signed up and set up tests to use with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) a CI I will use for my deployment.

Now I am stuck at stage where I need to create an `appspec.yml` file that will correctly deploy the application. I am not sure about this one at all, i.e. what source / destination should I specify etc.. Do I need to run my `npm build` script (creates dist/ folder) at this stage or during my CircleCI tests / builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` is the source of the files that will be deployed. The `destination` is the place where the files will be deployed to. You might want to run `npm build` after the files are copied over to the host (you can do this in AfterInstall hook). A list of available hooks as well as the detailed documentations are available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html for further reference.

Also please be more specific about the questions you have. It is hard to deduce what problems you are experiencing from `etc.`.